# Python code works but executable (made using py2exe) doesn't

Tags: python, selenium, py2exe

I have written a Python program which uses Selenium to get data from some websites. This means that my code needs 3 files: (1) a text file with some input arguments (2) firefox binary & (3) gecko driver

Now to share this with my colleagues I have converted this to executable using py2exe.

The program when executed from shell works absolutely fine. However, when same is executed through the executable, it results in various errors - these vary - (1) input arguments file not found (2) gecko driver not found (3) windows handle error 6 (not all of these errors occurring every time)
How do I ensure that it works as executable as well?

excerpts from the code:

```
gdir = str(os.path.realpath('.'))
gdir = gdir.replace('\\','\\\\')
inpArgPath = gdir + '\\\\inputArguments.txt'

ffpath = 'FirefoxPortable/App/Firefox64/firefox.exe'
binary = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary(ffpath)
gecko = gdir + '\\\\gecko\\\\geckodriver64.exe'

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.forbid_open_with",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.altClickSave",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=fp, executable_path=gecko)
```

selenium error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weeklyData_v5.py", line 18, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'inputArguments.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weeklyData_v5.py", line 18, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'inputArguments.txt'
```

Two more examples of errors:

```
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.pyc", line 144, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\common\service.pyc", line 81, in start
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver32.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

--

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=fp, executable_path=gecko)
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.pyc", line 144, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\common\service.pyc", line 74, in start
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 382, in __init__

  File "subprocess.pyc", line 515, in _get_handles

  File "subprocess.pyc", line 566, in _make_inheritable

WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to think that . is the path of your script. It's not. It's a path relative to the current working directory. This can be the directory the executable is in, and then things might work. But it can be somewhere completely different.

You need to instead use the first commandline argument given to your program which is the executable.

```
import os
import sys
BASE = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: thanks. I made this change, the code still works. However, when I run the executable (from py2exe), i get an error "NameError: name '__ file __' is not defined"

Comment: @dsauce see my updated answer, there is a speciality for py2exe.

Comment: Thanks. That made the code (as exe) work sometimes but i am still getting error sometimes (e.g. gecko driver not found) or "WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid". updated the question text with more error examples.